# Node.js: How to release Mongoose model from memory? (memory leak)

Tags: node.js, memory-leaks, mongoose, garbage-collection

How to release the model from memory after accessing it? I'm using `global.gc()` with `--expose-gc` option to see that this is eating my memory.

The following code creates 10000 collections:

```
// mongoose connection
var db = mongoose.createConnection(...);

// amount of collections
var amount = 10000;

// create collections (100/per second)
var sync = async.queue(function(n, cb) {
    var schema = new mongoose.Schema({
        data: mongoose.Schema.Types.Mixed
    });
    var collection = 'model_'+n;
    var model = db.model(collection, schema);
    setTimeout(function() { cb(); }, 10);
}, 1);

// push to queue
for(var i=0; i<amount; i++) {
    sync.push(i);
}

// done
sync.drain = function(err) {
    console.log('all '+amount+' models done');
};

// garbage collector (every second)
setInterval(function() {
    try { global.gc(); } catch(gcerr) { }
}, 1000);
```

The memory usage is increasing as collections are created and the memory is never released:

```
1 - Memory used: 30 MB
2 - Memory used: 36 MB
3 - Memory used: 42 MB
4 - Memory used: 48 MB
5 - Memory used: 54 MB
6 - Memory used: 61 MB
7 - Memory used: 65 MB
8 - Memory used: 71 MB
9 - Memory used: 77 MB
10 - Memory used: 82 MB
all 10000 models done
11 - Memory used: 86 MB
12 - Memory used: 86 MB
```

Any ideas how to purge the model from the memory manually without closing the connection?

**FOUND SOLUTION**

```
delete db.models[collection];
delete db.collections[collection];
delete db.base.modelSchemas[collection];
```

Comment: Why would you want to purge the internal model cache? Mongoose uses it for things like dereferencing in `population` operations.

Comment: The question is, how to free the memory Mongoose has eaten after you're done.

Comment: As you noted: if you are done then close the connections to purge the models attached to it. But if you have some need to keep the connection open without models see [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29632852/3194372).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These lines did the trick and got all my memory back:

```
delete db.models[collection];
delete db.collections[collection];
delete db.base.modelSchemas[collection];
```

Comment: Where & when do you have to add these lines to your code ?

Answer (score 2):

Mongoose exposes the model and schema caches via a property of either mongoose or the connection (depending on which you used to declare the model):

`[mongoose or connection ].models` // an object

`[mongoose or connection ].modelSchemas` // an object

Each is an object that uses the declared model name as a property name. You can then [`delete`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/delete) each model if you want to manually garbage collect them.

Comment: Thanks, but `delete db.models[collection];` only seems to delete half of the memory eaten and closing the connection doesn't do anything either. This might actually be a bug in Mongoose v4.0.1. I'm discussing it in [GitHub](https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/issues/2874).

Comment: @fedu The schemas were the other half which is why I mentioned them both above. So I'm not sure how this doesn't work. Anywho, whatever works. :)